# When creating a user with email, how to add elements in DB in Firebase in Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

So i'm new to using Firebase and I have been looking at the Firebase documentation but I haven't found how to do the following:

The user puts the following inputs: username, email, password, confirm password. 
When I call the "createUserWithEmailAndPassword", if it works, I want at the same time to create entries in the DB in Firebase. I tried writing the following line:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmailCreate, userPasswordCreate).then(function(){
  //do what I want
}).catch(function (error) {})
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong? 
Or do you have any suggestions as to how to add additional elements in the entry User using the uid that is created by the authentication method?

```
    function createUser() {
  //instance of database Firebase
  var database = firebase.database();
  //Get inputs from user
  var userUsername = document.getElementById("usernameCreation_Field").value;
  var userEmailCreate = document.getElementById("emailCreation_field").value;
  var userPasswordCreate = document.getElementById("passwordCreation_field").value;
  var userPassword2Create = document.getElementById("passwordCreation2_field").value;

  if (userPasswordCreate == userPassword2Create && userUsername.length > 0) {
    //If passwords match try to create user
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmailCreate, userPasswordCreate).catch(function (error) {
      // Handle Errors here when creating account
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      document.getElementById('createSuccess').style.display = 'block';
      document.getElementById('createSuccess').innerHTML = errorMessage;
    });
    //Passwords don't match
  } else if(userUsername.length == 0){
    document.getElementById('createSuccess').innerHTML = 'Username must be filled!';
    document.getElementById('createSuccess').style.display = 'block';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('createSuccess').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('createSuccess').innerHTML = 'Passwords don\'t match!';
  }

}

//Add new user to database
function setUserData(userId, username, email){
  firebase.database().ref('users/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    profile_picture : imageUrl,
    topScore : topScore
  });
}
```

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: What error are you getting the trying to create the user using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not calling `setUserData` anywhere, so that would definitely explain why nothing is written to the database.

You're probably looking to call if from the `then` of `createUser...`:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmailCreate, userPasswordCreate).then(function(userCredential) {
  setUserdata(userCredential.user.uid, userUsername, userEmailCreate);
}).catch(function (error) {
  // Handle Errors here when creating account
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  document.getElementById('createSuccess').style.display = 'block';
  document.getElementById('createSuccess').innerHTML = errorMessage;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer. :-) But where to you get the user.uid? It is created by firebase when creating the account no? So how do you retrieve the uid of the use?

Comment: if I do like you said, it doesn't retrieve the id of the just created user. The uid is "undefined"

Comment: Aha... it seems it's `user.user.uid` (see [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword)). I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much :) Works great!